# Need a report with varying columns depending on Date range parameter

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm quite a newbie with SQL. I'm currently working on an **Oracle database** and I've created a report that pulls up data depending on the date range parameter.

**The code is as follows:**

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT C.CUSTOMER_CODE
, MS.SALESMAN_NAME
, SUM(C.REVENUE_AMT) Rev_Amt


FROM 
    C_REVENUE_ANALYSIS C
  , M_CUSTOMER_H MC
  , M_SALESMAN MS


WHERE C.COMPANY_CODE = 'W1'
  AND C.CUSTOMER_CODE = MC.CUSTOMER_CODE
  AND MC.SALESMAN_CODE = MS.SALESMAN_CODE
  AND trunc(C.REVENUE_DATE) between to_date(<STARTDATE>,'YYYYMMDD') and to_date(<ENDDATE>,'YYYYMMDD')
  AND MS.COMPANY_CODE = '00'

GROUP BY C.CUSTOMER_CODE, MS.SALESMAN_NAME

ORDER BY C.CUSTOMER_CODE, MS.SALESMAN_NAME
```

**The resulting report for a date range from Jan 1st to April 30th is:**

```
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|Customer   |Salesman Name |Revenue Amount|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|Customer 1 |Salesman 1    |       5000.00|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|Customer 2 |Salesman 1    |       8000.00|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|Customer 3 |Salesman 2    |        300.00|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|Customer 4 |Salesman 3    |        600.00|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|Customer 5 |Salesman 3    |       5000.00|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|Customer 6 |Salesman 3    |       8000.00|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|Customer 7 |Salesman 4    |       9000.00|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|Customer 8 |Salesman 5    |       2000.00|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|Customer 9 |Salesman 6    |       1000.00|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|Customer10 |Salesman 6    |       5000.00|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|Customer11 |Salesman 7    |       6000.00|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|Customer12 |Salesman 8    |       8000.00|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
```

I need to show a break up of revenues for each Salesman for each month between Jan to April.

**So I would like the result to look like this:**

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|Customer   |Salesman Name |Rev for Jan|Rev for Feb|Rev for Mar|Rev for Apr|Total Rev Amt|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|Customer 1 |Salesman 1    |    1000.00|    1000.00|    1000.00|    2000.00|      5000.00|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|Customer 2 |Salesman 1    |    2000.00|    2000.00|    2000.00|    2000.00|      8000.00|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|Customer 3 |Salesman 2    |     100.00|       0.00|     100.00|     100.00|       300.00|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|Customer 4 |Salesman 3    |     100.00|     200.00|     100.00|     200.00|       600.00|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|Customer 5 |Salesman 3    |    1000.00|    2000.00|    1000.00|    1000.00|      5000.00|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|Customer 6 |Salesman 3    |    1000.00|    2000.00|    1000.00|    4000.00|      8000.00|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|Customer 7 |Salesman 4    |    2000.00|    2000.00|    3000.00|    2000.00|      9000.00|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|Customer 8 |Salesman 5    |     500.00|     400.00|     500.00|     600.00|      2000.00|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|Customer 9 |Salesman 6    |     200.00|     200.00|     200.00|     400.00|      1000.00|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|Customer10 |Salesman 6    |    1000.00|    1000.00|    2000.00|    1000.00|      5000.00|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|Customer11 |Salesman 7    |    2000.00|    2000.00|    1000.00|    1000.00|      6000.00|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|Customer12 |Salesman 8    |    2000.00|    2000.00|    2000.00|    2000.00|      8000.00|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

**Now, the challenge:**

The number of columns need to vary depending on the Date Range. Eg; when Jan to April is selected, I should get 4 columns for revenue plus 1 column for Total revenue. When Previous year's October to this year April is selected, I should get 7 columns for revenue plus 1 column for Total revenue.

Comment: If you are working with Oracle, then don't tag as SQL Server!

Comment: You will need to use decode, have removed my answer since it would not have satisfied your requirement

Comment: What is 'decode' and how do I use it? Thank you for your answer though. It was the most sensible one.

Comment: Pivoting the data based on the month is easy enough, especially if you are on 11g (but you've tagged for 10g too, which is confusing). A dynamic number of columns based on the data is not easy though; it's possible with dynamic SQL and there are some clever solutions out there, but it might be overkill. Can your report show zero-value columns for the rest of the year, maybe?

Comment: Thank you Alex. My apologies, I'm using Oracle11g. If I do have zero-value columns, it won't quite work because what if the user selects a date range of August of last year to the current month of April. I could have a 'yearly' date range for the report where the other columns show zero values. But that won't really give any value to the report. I would really like to employ Dynamic SQL and get this as the boss wants it.  --- PLEASE can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add **trunc(C.REVENUE_DATE,'MM')**  in select & group by. Then your result will be in column wise. Then you have to do pivot to get as you shown.

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT C.CUSTOMER_CODE
, MS.SALESMAN_NAME
, SUM(C.REVENUE_AMT) Rev_Amt
trunc(C.REVENUE_DATE,'MM')

from ...
...
where ...
GROUP BY C.CUSTOMER_CODE, MS.SALESMAN_NAME , trunc(C.REVENUE_DATE,'MM')

ORDER BY C.CUSTOMER_CODE, MS.SALESMAN_NAME
```

Comment: Even if we group by trunc(c.revenue_Date,'MM'), don't you think that we shall still be getting the data for different months in Rows and not in columns.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I appreciate it. But when I added that code as you suggested, I only got one column giving me a complete date. eg; 2015-01-01T00:00:00-08:00